# Flex PopUpManager pop up a compoent and the compoent will change position

Tags: apache-flex, popup

I need pop up a component on the top of the first item in a List, and it works fine. The issue is when I scroll down the scrollbar, the pop component will change position. What I want is the pop can fix on the first time.

**Issue**: when drag the scrollbar down, the pop component position will change. I want it to remain the same position.

application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:popup="components.popup.*"
    width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
            <popup:OrderView width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Application>
```

OrderView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:VGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          gap="0">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.containers.Panel;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            private var panel:Panel;

            private function pop():void {
                if(!panel) {
                    panel = new Panel();
                    panel.title = "I'm a pop";
                    panel.width = 150;
                    panel.height = 100;
                }
                var pos:Point = item1.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));
                panel.move(pos.x + 100, pos.y + 10);
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(panel, parent as DisplayObject, false);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="item1" backgroundColor="#00ff00" width="600" height="200">
        <s:Button label="Pop Window" click="pop()"/>
        <s:Label text="item1...." left="300" top="100" color="#ffffff"/>
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="item2" backgroundColor="#0000ff" width="600" height="300">
        <s:Label text="item2...." left="300" top="100" color="#ffffff"/>
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="item3" backgroundColor="#000000" width="600" height="300">
        <s:Label text="item3...." left="300" top="100" color="#ffffff"/>
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="item4" backgroundColor="#ff0000" width="600" height="300">
        <s:Label text="item4...." left="300" top="100" color="#ffffff"/>
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="item5" backgroundColor="#ee66ff" width="600" height="300">
        <s:Label text="item5...." left="300" top="100" color="#ffffff"/>
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
</s:VGroup>
```

First time pop window position is fine

[image]

After scroll:

[image]

Comment: Please share additional details.  What is parent?  What are X and Y?  Is your list using virtual layout?

Comment: @Reboog711, I have edited the question. parent means the List's parent. X,Y are just a specific number such like 200 etc. I just ignore the trivial thing.

Comment: If you are positioning the pop up based on the List's parent; it makes very little sense to me that the popup would move when scrolling the list.  Can you provide a runnable sample?

Comment: @Reboog711, I have put the code here.

Comment: Rather than using a pop up and the PopUpManager, why not try making the "popup" be part if the renderer?

Comment: @SunilD. Yeah, this is another workaround. I just wonder if it is possible to achieve by PopUpManager